# How to change the URL of single post of custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created the custom post type `guides` in wordpress. So, I can see all the posts of `guides` under the URL: `http://example.com/guides/`. When I click to see the detail view of any post of guides, the URL structure has been `http://example.com/guides/any-post-of-guide/`. Here I just want: for all guides, the url should have guides and for the single post of guide, the url structure should have guide (instead of guides). Can you tell me someone how to do this.

The code below what I have done and tried:

```
$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => 'ml-vault.php',
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'guides'),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title','editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your `rewrite` argument to:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'guide', 'with_front' => false),
```

2. Add rewrite rule for archive link:

```
add_action('init', function()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^guides/?$', 'index.php?post_type=guides', 'top');
});
```

3. Flush your permalink structure and now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reconsidered the argument rewrite in your args array? More about rewrite here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite